# Different ways to use angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have been working on angular js and i found that are many ways to create a module, a controller, etc...

For example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

and:

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
```

If i want to create a controller (*First way*):

```
app.controller('myController', [...]);
```

create a controller (*Second way*):

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', [...]);
```

Really... what is the difference?

Thanks!

Comment: Other than the first way is a lot cleaner and more concise?

Comment: The difference between the two first pieces of code is that on the first one you set a variable to store the result. The rest is just chaining.

Comment: There is no difference between them. But for me I think you should use `Second way`, you will don't have to consider the app variable, you can get app module anywhere by `angular.module('myApp')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular.module('myApp', []) is the setter for a module that returns the instance once it is created. Putting var app = in front just keeps a reference to the modules JavaScript object. The empty array after the module name is the dependency list. We pass in an empty dependency list to distinguish it from a getter call and let Angular know that it is a setter call and we are creating a module.

angular.module('myApp') is the getter for a module and returns the JavaScript object. The difference here is that there is no dependency list so Angular knows that it is retrieving a module that has already been created.

When you are in the same file it is OK the keep a reference to the module with a local variable like app but when you are creating controllers in different files you should not rely on the existence of a global variable call app and should retrieve the module with a getter call.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference actually, it's exactly the same.

This app.controller(...) is equal to angular.module('myApp').controller(...)

because you declared a variable called app which is equal to angular.module()

And the chaining thing : angular.module.controller is all of you 3 exemples combined.

Putting angular.module() into a variable called app or whatever just makes the syntax easier that's all ^^